# Get relative path of XML File located in another project but Same Solution

Tags: c#, xml

I have found many Articles and Questions about finding an XML file but all of them are for Same Project.

Suppose I have my Project structure as shown below:

```
ABC       <------ Solution
|--ABC.Data         <------ Project
|  |--XMLFiles      <-------Folder
|     |--AA.xml
|
|--ABC.Client      <------ Project
|  |--ViewModels   <-------Folder
|     |-MainViewModel.cs
```

Now I would like to load AA.xml file in MainViewModel.cs using `XDocument.Load(....path.....)`.

So, how can I get `path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to move back from the executing assembly folder on parent of *ABC.Data* and *ABC.Client*. For example the executing assembly is located in *ABC.Client->ViewModels->Bin->Debug*

```
XDocument.Load("../../../../../ABC.Data/ABC.Data/AA.xml");
```

But practically I see no use of it as the project hierarchy wont be there when you deploy the application. If you have XML file that need to be accessed by multiple assemblies the simply put that xml file in Execution folder. All the assemblies will be able to access it.

You can also make a separate assembly that exposes the AA.xml file data for read and write for all other projects by adding reference of that assembly to those projects. I would prefer this method.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. Can you give an example of your preferred method?

Comment: You have to make a class library that will provide methods for access the xml you want then you have to consume that library in project who want to access the aa.xml file. Read this article for make and consuming assembly, http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/9c667330-0966-4e38-a689-61fed9cbbb4c/Creating%20C

Comment: Your idea is very much similar to implementation of wcf service. Thanks once again for giving me the right direction

Answer (score 1):

you need a couple of settings to make your scenario work

first right click the xml file(or any file you want to access) and set 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy Always' and when you build or publish the folder structure of that file(AA.xml in your case) will be created on bin or publish(web project) folder and you have simply have to write this code

```
var path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath+"\\bin";//path to you bin
```

if you are using winforms

```
var path = Application.StartupPath;//path to you bin
```

finally

```
var fullpath=path+"\\XMLFiles\\AA.xml";
XDocument.Load(fullpath) ;
```

however the better approach will be to create a Helper Class that will fetch the xml content for you application such as

```
public static class XMLHelpers
{
 public static XMLDocument GetXML(string KEY)
 {
    string file="";
    switch(KEY)
    {
      case "AA": file=Path.Combine(file,"AA.txt");
      break;
    }
     var xmldoc=new XMLDocument();
     xmldoc.Load(file);
     return xmldoc;
 }
}
```